# Web Services sql server con Android Studio?

Tags: php, android, android-studio, sql-server

Bueno he estado desarrollando un web service entre mysql y android studio...esto lo hago mediante un archivo php...pero ahora mi pregunta es...con sql server como seria? He estado buscando ejemplos y no encuentro que lo unan mediante un archivo php...mas bien veo que la coneccion siempre es por asp .net, se puede mediante algun archivo php? (Aqui pondre algo de mi codigo que lo hago con php ya que se necesita poner una linea de codigo para poder hacer una pregunta).

Codigo:

```
$json=array();

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);

    $consulta="select documento,nombre,profesion from usuario";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

    while($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $json['usuario'][]=$registro;
    }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo json_encode($json);
```

Mas lo que necesito es salir de dudas... :s

Comment: esto te sirve? https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo, simplemente envez de utilizar `mysqli_connect`, utiliza `sqlsrv_connect`.

Aquí la docu oficial de PHP para guiarte en como hacer la conexión a SQLServer https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Answer (score -1):

Lo podes hacer. Necesitás instalar el driver para sql server en las extensiones de php.
Y la programación, por obvias razones, la tenes que hacer con PDO en lugar de mysqli.

Por si también te genera alguna duda, podés instalar php en IIS, si quisieras usar IIS en lugar de Apache o nginx.

Abajo te dejo un link como para arrancar.

Cosas a tener en cuenta:
- La versión de SQL server
- La versión de PHP, si es 32 o 64, bits y si es Thread safe o no.

Es para hacerlo un sábado tranquilo y con tiempo.

[Referencia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Ok compañero, entonces lo probare a ver que me sale. Pense que se tenia que desarrollar solo con asp o .net ya que solo veo ejemplo sobre eso para hacer web service con sql server y android studio